# building drop down select in form: code block not supported in this context

Tags: asp.net, forms, loops, drop-down-menu

I am trying to do something i thought was straightforward [able to do it in PHP this way] but aspx is complaining... the code should build a drop down menu with the numbers from x to y and i wrote it as:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID='DOBD'><asp:ListItem value=''>---</asp:ListItem>
<% for (int i = 1;i<32;i++) { %>
<asp:ListItem value='<%= i %>'><%= i %></asp:ListItem>
<% } %>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

i am getting the code block error and not sure what to do. 
thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: you are trying to do php in asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

Add items in the codebehind class. You can access any control using `id` of the control:

```
this.DOBD.Items.Add(new ListItem("----"));
for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
{
    this.DOBD.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
}
```

also, you can leave your `<asp:ListItem value=''>---</asp:ListItem>` but in this case you need to set `AppendDataBoundItems` to `true`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DOBD" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Also, solution without codebehind class:

```
<%
    for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
    {
        this.DOBD.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
    }
%>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DOBD" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="---"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You can find your codebehind class in `Page` directive: search for `CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"`.  It can be that no codebehind for this page, then checkout second sample

Comment: thank you @samich for your help. You may have figured out, I'm not an aspx coder usually, so pls forgive me if i ask another 'newbie' q. 'add items in codebehind class': where do i find this & where exactly do i copy this code? its not inline on form like my original code snippet is? 
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID='DOBD' AppendDataBoundItems="true"> <asp:ListItem value=''>---</asp:ListItem>
   <%  for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)  {
       this.DOBD.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
   }  %>   </asp:DropDownList>                                       Again, thanks in advance!

Comment: It's inline code, but not in scope of server control, where inline code is not allowed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [Samich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463709/building-drop-down-select-in-form-code-block-not-supported-in-this-context/7463744#7463744), you can use a DataSource to fill the dropdown:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID='DOBD' 
     DataSource='<%# System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(1, 32) %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>

<script runat="server"> 
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
     if(! IsPostback) {
        DOBD.DataBind();
     }
  }
</script>
```

or a ObjectDataSource

Comment: +1, Yes, the only thing is need to bind at least OnLoad, because you will not be able to read the data on the server if you bind it on PreRender

Comment: and need to check for IsPostback to avoid rebinding at each postback. thank you :)